# Wit.ai HTTP api using php curl

Tags: php, api, http, curl, wit.ai

Hi i have been following documentation of **wit.ai HTTP api** and i have built a php chat application I want to integrate wit.ai bot with it can any one help me with it so far i have created stories in wit and i have used https://api.wit.ai/message and https://api.wit.ai/converse and i able to communicate with my but I am still confused how to make the bot execute an action.

Comment: Is your question how to use the API?

Comment: yea kind of because i'm not able to make out flow on how to make the wit bot reply and how can it perform execution of functions